# Query FireStore Collection for document Key

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I set a documents key in a collection to the userId, and now I would like to get that one document in a snapshot for realtime results:

```
Ref = firestore().collection('Ref');
Ref.where("[.key]","==",this.id).onSnapshot(snap => {
      if (!snap.empty) {
        snap.docChanges().forEach(change => {
          if (change.type === "modified") {
            // update model here for charts
            this.user = change.doc.data()
          }
          if (change.type === "added") {
            // create a new chart
            this.user = change.doc.data()

          }

        })
      }
    })
```

I tried `key` `.key` `[.key]` nothing is working. I would like to watch this one document for changes while its user is logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get an element based on it's id, there is no need to use a query, simply get only a reference to that document id. So please change the following line of code:

```
 Ref.where("[.key]","==",this.id).onSnapshot(/* ... */)
```

to

```
 Ref.doc(key).onSnapshot(/* ... */)
```

**Edit:**

```
var doc = db.collection('Ref').doc(key);
var observer = doc.onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {
  console.log(`Received doc snapshot: ${docSnapshot}`);
  // Get data from the docSnapshot object
}, err => {
  console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
});
```

Comment: How is `Ref` defined?

Comment: Ref is a collection firestore().collection('Ref')

Comment: Oh, I udnerstand. Please see my updated answer. Should be simply `.doc(key)`. Does it work this way?

Comment: almost `snap.docChanges is not a function` how do i then listen for change events?

Comment: Please see again my updated answer. Does it work now?